# Can't Detect Gif Selection From TextInput In React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, gif, expo-go

Using react native `TextInput` (on version 0.72.10), I am unable to detect when a GIF has been selected by a user. Consequently, one is unable to retrieve the GIF data and implement any sort of logic to display the said GIF in another component better suited to display this data.

Looking at the documentation for `TextInput`, it seems that there is no default callback to detect any sort of GIF or image selection, so instead I opted to use the [React Native Keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-keyboard) package with a `onImageChange`, but the callback does not appear to execute at all. The callback seems to be detected in vscode so I would think it is linking in some sense. Sample code is below (can also be seen in [this expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@randyk98/trusting-red-blueberries)):

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [debug, setDebug] = useState('No image change detected yet :(');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const _onImageChange = (event) => {
    setDebug("Can detect image change!");
    const {uri, linkUri, mime, data} = event.nativeEvent;
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{debug}</Text>
      <TextInput
          value={message}
          onChangeText={setMessage}
          placeholder={'Comments?'}
          style={styles.input}
          onImageChange={_onImageChange}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  input: {
    width: 250,
    height: 44,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'paleturquoise',
  },
});
```

Comment: TextInput from react-native doesn't have an onImageChange property. However, I'm assuming you copied and pasted the code from that snack. Are you sure you're importing as stated in the react-native-image-keyboard docs?